# Kali Linux ppa:repository

Tags: apt, kali-linux, repository, ppa

How can I remove repositories in Kali Linux? I have tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

But I don't know how to apply this to:

```
Ign:1 //ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu oneiric InRelease
Ign:2 ://ppa.launchpad.net/alecive/antigone/ubuntu oneiric InRelease
error:3 ://ppa.launchpad.net//ubuntu oneiric InRelease                       
  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Read:4 ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu oneiric Release [9 759 B]
Read:5 ppa.launchpad.net/alecive/antigone/ubuntu oneiric Release [9 737 B]
Read:7 ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]
Good:6 ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Read:8 ppa.launchpad.net/alecive/antigone/ubuntu oneiric Release.gpg [316 B]
Ign:7 ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu oneiric Release.gpg
Ign:8 ppa.launchpad.net/alecive/antigone/ubuntu oneiric Release.gpg
Reading packagelists… Finished
```

Comment: What do you want to apply it to? Why are you even using PPAs with Kali in the first place? And to remove them, just edit the files in `/etc/sources.d` manually. Kali is a tool designed for experts, don't expect it to make things easy for you.

Comment: Okay how do i find /etc/sources.d?

Comment: It's at `/etc/sources.d`. If you don't understand what that means, you really should think about using another operating system. There's nothing wrong with being new, but you should learn how to walk before trying to run. [Please read this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/).

Comment: Thanks your an angel i did as you said and edit the files with nano in the terminal now my updates are working normal. You saved me. One questions should i avoid ppa packages to Kali Linux because i tried to do this according to the link https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/02/21/kali-linux-add-ppa-repository-add-apt-repository/?

Comment: No, you should avoid Kali Linux! Seriously. Don't. The only thing Kali will give a new user that another Linux distribution will not is pain. Anything you can do on Kali you can do on another system which will be easier to use. Also, read the links you post: ["there’s a chance that by adding untested and unsupported PPA repositories and application you might end up breaking your installation."](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/02/21/kali-linux-add-ppa-repository-add-apt-repository/).  That's from the very page you linked to. Please don't use Kali, you will thank me later.

Comment: Yeah i understand you but i have an 32-bit computer that i am running Kali linux on and i tried to download ubuntu but the real problem is that Ubuntu has dropped 32 bits-version and the latest was Ubuntu is 16.2 and other distros has also dropped 32 bits. And i don't throw away my 32-computer beacuse we in the west throw away so much thing.

Comment: Fair enough, but just because Ubuntu is dropping 32 bit is no reason to use Kali. [Debian](https://www.debian.org/distrib/) still has 32 bit support, as do [open SuSe Tumbleweed](https://software.opensuse.org/distributions/tumbleweed), [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) and loads of others.

Comment: Fedora maybe will also drop 32 bit repositary                                                                                                                                        https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-i686-Drop-Kernel-Plus maybe

Comment: Then use Debian. Kali is based on Debian so Debian will support 32 for as long as Kali will. But do you _really_ have a 32bit machine? You are using a computer that is more than 10 or 15 years old?

Comment: Yes i have but i dosen't use kali linux as my main computer!

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p.list

sudo rm -rf etc/apt/sources.list.d/i2p.list

sudo apt update
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations? In particular, what should readers look for to identify that `i2p.list` is the file to remove?